# Yii how to include ssh2 library

Tags: php, yii, set-include-path

I am Newbie in Yii and i am trying to include the library ssh2 in Yii, I made:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'/home/local/php/');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ip = "192.168.199.17";
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
```

It gives:

```
Error 500
include(Math_BigInteger.php): failed to open stream: No existe el fichero o el directorio


Notice: Use of undefined constant NET_SSH2_DISCONNECT_BY_APPLICATION - assumed 'NET_SSH2_DISCONNECT_BY_APPLICATION' in /home/local/php/Net/SSH2.php on line 2937
```

But it works propetly out of yii, I mean as a simple php file in htdocs.
So I guess I am not including them in Yii....

Thanks all!

Comment: Is this using phpseclib?  I don't see anywhere that it tries to include `Math_BigInteger.php` so not sure where that error is coming from.  It tries to load `Math/BigInteger.php`.  Maybe the Yii autoloader is getting in they way when it calls `class_exists` it tries to load the wrong file.

Comment: have you installed `pear install Math_BigInteger`